# Is there any way to have two programs access the same file

Tags: windows, process

I have tow programs running on my windows computer that I need to access the same files at the same time.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the parameters to `CreateFile` specifies the sharing mode. Both applications have to agree to share reading and/or writing. If one or both of the applications are going to write to the file then you need to use `LockFileEx` or a mutex for synchronization.